# POI Set foreground color not working in if statement

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am doing some code that compares two sheets and outputs a file with the matching cells in green and the others in red.

**Problematic section (see full code at the end)**

```
CellStyle style = cellOutputFile.getCellStyle();

if (isCellContentEqual(cellComparisonFile1, cellComparisonFile2) == true)
{
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
}
else
{
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
}

style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
cellOutputFile.setCellStyle(style);
```

**Problem**

This code always displays ALL cells as green, even if, when debugging, the else statement is triggered and the style is set to have a red background.

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Full Code**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < workbookComparisonFile1.getNumberOfSheets(); i++)
    {
        sheetComparisonFile1 = workbookComparisonFile1.getSheetAt(i);
        sheetComparisonFile2 = workbookComparisonFile2.getSheet(sheetComparisonFile1.getSheetName());
        sheetOutputFile = workbookOutputFile.getSheet(sheetComparisonFile1.getSheetName());

        System.out.println(sheetComparisonFile1.getLastRowNum());

        if (sheetComparisonFile2 != null)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sheetComparisonFile1.getLastRowNum(); j++)
            {
                Row rowComparisonFile1 = sheetComparisonFile1.getRow(j);
                Row rowComparisonFile2 = sheetComparisonFile2.getRow(j);
                Row rowOutputFile = sheetOutputFile.getRow(j);

                if ((rowComparisonFile1 != null && rowComparisonFile2 != null)
                        && (rowComparisonFile1.getLastCellNum() == rowComparisonFile2.getLastCellNum()))
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < rowComparisonFile1.getLastCellNum(); k++)
                    {
                        Cell cellComparisonFile1 = rowComparisonFile1.getCell(k);
                        Cell cellComparisonFile2 = rowComparisonFile2.getCell(k);
                        Cell cellOutputFile = rowOutputFile.getCell(k);

                        if (cellComparisonFile1 != null && cellComparisonFile2 != null)
                        {
                            CellStyle style = cellOutputFile.getCellStyle();

                            if (isCellContentEqual(cellComparisonFile1, cellComparisonFile2) == true)
                            {
                                style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
                            }

                            style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                            cellOutputFile.setCellStyle(style);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

public boolean isCellContentEqual(Cell cell1, Cell cell2)
{
    if (getCellContents(cell1).equals(getCellContents(cell2)) == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Sheet: " + cell1.getRow().getSheet().getSheetName() +
                " Cell1: " + cell1.getRow().getRowNum() + "-" + cell1.getColumnIndex() + " "
                + getCellContents(cell1).equals(getCellContents(cell2)));
    }
    return getCellContents(cell1).equals(getCellContents(cell2));
}

public String getCellContents(Cell cell)
{
    DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();

    return df.formatCellValue(cell);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styles are created at the workbook level, not the cell level.  Try the following code but this may fail if the workbook style table is full.  Modify the if/else logic of your inner loop as such:

```
if (isCellContentEqual(cellComparisonFile1, cellComparisonFile2) == true)
{
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.cloneStyleFrom(cellOutputFile.getCellStyle());
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    cellOutputFile.setCellStyle(style);
}
else
{
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.cloneStyleFrom(cellOutputFile.getCellStyle());
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    cellOutputFile.setCellStyle(style);
}
```

*edit* code sample updated to copy preexisting style before changing the fill foreground color and fill pattern

Comment: Thank you for the answer! While this solves the red / green dilemna, it removes all the current style (size, font, alignment, etc.) from each of the cell. Is there a way to keep the original cell's style and just add the color?

Comment: The CellStyle class has a method cloneStyleFrom(CellStyle source) that will copy all the style information from another CellStyle onto itself.

Comment: @BenoitGoderre Please mark this answer as the correct answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: Of course, after the code changes are done since the code in the answer is not working :).

Comment: @BenoitGoderre Your suggested changes will not work unless every cell being turned green/red had identical styles before the green/red colors were applied.  Think of these styles as global variables referenced by every cell that uses one of these styles.  Changes made to the global redStyle will affect every cell that was previously set to use the redStyle.